# Position div to bottom of a different div, without using Absolute

Tags: html, css, image, css-float

I have one div in another div. The inner div has margins of 0, auto to centralize it. However, I can't get it to float to the bottom without making it absolute. Is there anyway of making a relative div float to the bottom of a normal div?

Comment: Some code would give us a better understanding of the issue

Comment: What's wrong with using `position:absolute`?

Comment: i have text within the same div. and for responsiveness the image overlays the text when the screen is small.

Comment: can we see a fiddle ?

Comment: Can't you make it absolute and then give the outer div a bottom padding that matches the height of the inner div? That way any text inside won't be covered by that inner div.

Comment: I've tried this, but when there is little text then the outer is too large and the margin is not needed.

Comment: @user3506938 Try this demo - http://jsfiddle.net/zmopg50q/

Comment: it works, however depending on how much text i have, i need to change the translateY % Any way of getting around that?

Comment: when little text then 50%, when lots of text then 100%

Comment: see the reivsed - http://jsfiddle.net/zmopg50q/2/

Comment: @user3506938 you could add text or anything inside a container `div` and add `height: 100%;` to that container div and remove the `top: 100%;` to `.inner` like this demo - http://jsfiddle.net/b6pzaq7b/

Comment: nope, it still doesnt work with little text, but works with lots of text

Comment: @user3506938 It's working fine for me - http://jsfiddle.net/t2dpxqdh/ or http://jsfiddle.net/Ln0xfd71/ or http://jsfiddle.net/b8z8k44n/

Comment: dno why its not working for me. the image is bigger and about 50px higher from the bottom

Comment: got it working in the end.. with absolute and padding :/

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Without using `position: absolute`, you'd have to vertically align it.

You can use `vertical-align: bottom` which, according to [**the docs**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align):

> The vertical-align CSS property specifies the vertical alignment of an inline or table-cell box.

So, either set the outer div as an inline element, or as a `table-cell`:

```css
#outer {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

#inner {
  border: 1px solid green;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: how would i also make the inner central, aligned in the middle?

Comment: `text-align: center` on the outer, or `margin: 0 auto` on the inner.

Comment: @user3506938 - If you're talking about vertically center, it's `vertical-align: middle;`

Comment: But this aligns everything in the parent div to the bottom. What if you just want the inner div at the bottom but everything else aligned to the top?

Comment: You can use Flexbox nowadays to solve this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49068854/5993042

Answer (score 19):

Nowadays you can simply use `display: flex` for all these alignment issues.

In your case you can simply make the parent a flex, flex-direction `column` (the default is row) and `justify-content: flex-end`. The advantage of this approach is that it also works if you have multiple items in the parent.

If you have multiple ones and want to have them all aligned from the beginning of the parent till the end, you can change `justify-content` to another property such as `space-between` or `space-evenly`.

```css
#outer {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#inner {
  border: 1px solid green;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unless you want to fully support IE. This does not work in IE 10

Comment: You're right. I might be a lucky dev that doesn't have to provide support for IE11, but IE10 has `0.12%` usage. Depends on your use-case ofc. (https://caniuse.com/usage-table)

Comment: This answer worked immediately for me. I wanted to position the element 40px off the bottom so I just added a margin.

Answer (score 10):

Add this styling to the inner div.

```
position: relative;
top: 100%;
transform: translateY(-100%);
```

Comment: Someone voted this down, but did not say why, which would have been helpful. I think this works, but is there a disadvantage to it? I can't remember.

Comment: i cant seem to find a disadvantage which is probably why i posted it seeing as its a three line solution. heres a jsfiddle showing that regardless of the document position the div stays at the bottom of its parent div without changing the positioning type. https://jsfiddle.net/Zmgaddo/1qgb5cu4/

Answer (score 4):

See this,

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

[CSS positioning at the bottom without absolute positioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39883564/css-positioning-at-the-bottom-without-absolute-positioning/39883779#39883779)

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found, unless your content is a static-height, was to do it with jquery like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  inner_height = $('#inner-div').height();
  outer_height = $('#outer-div').height();
  margin_calc = (outer_height - inner_height)
  $('#inner-div').css('margin-top', (margin_calc+'px'));
});
```

This will work for a column-div within a containing-div, if another column's height is larger.

It is unbelievable this simple thing is not 'built in' via a css-property (i.e. "float: bottom"), that doesn't break everything else with absolutes, etc.

Comment: "float" wouldn't make sense. The intent of float is to move elements to the left or right of other elements on the same line. It's use was much abused where CSS had no alternative methods.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this by setting to top value to 100%.

## Html

```
<div class="outer">
<div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

## CSS

```
.outer {height:400px;width:400px;background:#eaeaea;}
.inner {position:relative;top:100%;height:50px; width:50px; background:#fad400;}
```

check out this fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/62wqufgk/

Comment: this doesn't seem to work. the image is too low and out of the div

Comment: The user wants the inner div to be aligned to the bottom of the outer div. The provided fiddle (look at it) puts the "inner" (which is not "inner" anymore) *below* the "outer" one.