# CSS positioning at the bottom without absolute positioning

Tags: html, css

How can I position an element so it is always on the bottom of the container without using 'absolute' positioning?
I have a container containing 2 elements and one of them is text description so it can be as big as the text is. I would like to position second element at the bottom of the page regardless if the text in previous div is empty, and If text isn't empty I want to have padding of 10px between them

Comment: Load the Fiddle

Comment: Please post enough code to create a minimal example so we can help you.

Comment: Also please explain why absolute positioning is not a good solution for you.

Comment: @hunter 

https://jsfiddle.net/ec7qxtfr/

Here is my code. I would like to position btn-container at the bottom even if the description is empty. In case description isn't empty I would like it to be 10 px away from description. Absolute isn't solution because that way I cannot add some padding between the end of the div with description and btn-container div

Comment: @ZoliSzabo I would like to position btn-container at the bottom even if the description is empty. In case description isn't empty I would like it to be 10 px away from description. Absolute isn't solution because that way I cannot add some padding between the end of the div with description and btn-container div

Comment: @Irma, take a look at my solution below, I believe it achieves what you're looking for.

Comment: @iamhju your solution is great but somehow it doesn't work for me. For example take a look at the border-top of my second element which is container of buttons (http://prntscr.com/cqb258) You can see overlapping of the description and the border

Comment: @iamhju it worked! thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Updated:** JSFiddle with `flexbox` applied to your code.

https://jsfiddle.net/ec7qxtfr/1/

`flexbox` can help you achieve this. Add the following to your parent container.

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

The next bit is for the `10px` padding you wanted. This will target the first child element inside the container.

```
.child:first-child {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

As long as the first child `div` is present, even if you don't have any content (no paragraphs), the second `div` will still be pushed to the bottom of the container thanks to `flexbox`. Likewise, you can comment out the `height` property to verify that the `padding` is present between the two child elements.

Check out the JSFiddle below. You can adjust the height in the parent container to confirm that the second div stays at the bottom of the container.

https://jsfiddle.net/o3r40keu/5/

Note: this solution will assume you will only have two child elements inside this particular parent container.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

You can use flexbox.
If you set the container to

```
.container-class {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

You can then set the child's margin top to `auto`.

```
.child {
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

The HTML could look like:

```
 <section class="container-class">
   <p class="child">...</p>
 </section>
```

You might need to set a certain height on the container for this to work, but the gist of the solution is using flexbox + margin-top: auto on the element you want to stick to the bottom.
The padding and other styles you want to achieve should work as expected, no tricks.

Note that you'll need to prefix your flexbox props, i.e:

```
display: -webkit-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: flex;
-webkit-box-orient: vertical;
-webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
      flex-direction: column;
```

Comment: After a lot of wandering, I got this . Thanks :)