# Align div to bottom of content without using position absolute

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox, internet-explorer-9

I know this question has been asked a number of times but I keep seeing the answer for using...

```
postion: absolute;
bottom: 0;
```

However, it doesn't really work in my case, so was looking for other suggestions.

And answers for using flex don't seem to work because of my column layout. I am also pretty knew to flex so I don't know it awfully well.

I have an image on the left that has a set width of 145px, but can differ in height.

On the right, I have a div that contains 2 divs (`TimelineAddress` & `TimelineFavouriteUser`) with spans inside each one. One for property address and another with a user name and some text appended. I would like the div `TimelineFavouriteUser` to sit at the bottom so it is inline with the bottom of the image. See diagram below.

```
 ----------- ----------------------------
|Image      | Address - Dynamic Length   |
|Can be     |                            |
|different  |                            |
|heights    |                            |
|           |                            |
|           |                            |
|           |                            |
|           |                            |
|           | User and text at bottom    |
 ----------- ----------------------------
```

This can be achieved by using

```
postion: absolute;
bottom: 0;
```

However, when it comes to responsiveness and lower resolutions the address can overlap the text at the bottom as the address text breaks into more an and more lines. See image below.

[image]

I have used some javascript to dynamically add the correct `margin-top` to 
`TimelineFavouriteUser`, although, I'd prefer a CSS only solution as the function that runs the calculation for `margin-top` value gets called a lot as there could be 100's of these elements on the screen.

I know this may be possible with `flex`, **however, we need to support at least `IE9` so if there was a solution for `IE9`, that would be great**.

If not then I can perhaps come up with a solution for browsers where `flex` is not supported if `flex` is the best solution.

I have a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2p0go3xc/1/) if you'd like to test it out for yourself.

Comment: Hey here is one that is doing almost the same thing. wont work in IE9 without javascript though - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56475464/prevent-image-from-expanding-beyond-other-elements-of-flex-row

Comment: Try using css grid. Oops IE9

Comment: If you dont want to use position: absolute than you can try to use vertical-align: bottom. you can try to refer the answer in this thread. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26124865/position-div-to-bottom-of-a-different-div-without-using-absolute/26125052

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you a polyfill for the flexbox maybe something like:
https://github.com/jonathantneal/flexibility

otherwise you would have to fiddle around with display:table, floats and hardcoded pixel values

Answer (score -1):

You can use flex for the same

```
align-items:flex-end;
```

here's a fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/karantewari/pw4hsqry/

Answer (score -1):

Untested. With CSS vendor prefix.

```css
div {
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
  -ms-grid-columns: 1fr 2fr;
      grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
  -ms-grid-rows: 2fr 1fr;
      grid-template-rows: 2fr 1fr;
  height: calc(100vh - 1rem);
  width: 100%;
}

section {
  background-color: lightpink;
}

section:first-child {
  background-color: lightblue;
  -ms-grid-row-span: 2;
      grid-row-end: span 2;
}

section:last-child {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <section>X</section>
  <section>y</section>
  <section>z</section>
</div>
```